# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token, tried all solutions here but nothing has worked

Tags: javascript, error-handling, social-networking, jdeveloper

I am running the following codes:

```
var jq = document.createElement('script');
jq.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);
jQuery.noConflict();
```

and it gives me:

```
ƒ (a,b){return new n.fn.init(a,b)}
```

but when I run the second part:

```
 window.setInterval(function(){
    var x = 0;
    $("button:contains(‘Follow’)").each(
    function(){ if($(this).text()=="Follow"){
    if(x==1) return false; 
    $(this).trigger("click");
    $(‘._gs38e’).scrollTop($(‘._gs38e’)[0].scrollHeight);
    x++;}})
    $(‘._gs38e’).scrollTop($(‘._gs38e’)[0].scrollHeight); console.log(‘loop’);
    }, 60000);
```

I keep getting the following error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Comment: Replace the backticks (as seen around `Follow`, `._gs38e` and `loop`) by regular quotes.

Comment: At what line are you getting the SyntaxError?

Comment: Hi Zim,
thanks for your help. I replaced all the backticks as you suggested and got the following error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list"

Comment: Hey Bas, I am getting the SyntaxError after I run the second bid of the code

Answer (score 1):

Update your code as below:

```
window.setInterval(function(){
    var x = 0;
    $("button:contains(‘Follow’)").each(
        function(){ if($(this).text()=="Follow"){
            if(x==1) return false; 
            $(this).trigger("click");
            $('._gs38e').scrollTop($('._gs38e')[0].scrollHeight);
            x++;}})
    $('._gs38e').scrollTop($('._gs38e')[0].scrollHeight); 
    console.log('loop');
}, 10000);
```

Comment: Hey Mayur, thanks for your help. I tried your code and got the following error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollHeight' of undefined
    at <anonymous>:9:43"